# Reverse an accidental downvote

Tags: support, down-votes

I just noticed (by looking at my reputation) that I accidentally downvoted the following answer:

[Oscillation of the summatory Möbius function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/273845/oscillation-of-the-summatory-m%C3%B6bius-function/273873#273873)

This was (probably) because I was reading the question in my tablet computer (not the best one in the market), and I wanted to upvote that answer, but accidentally pressed the downvote button with my stupid finger.  I tried to upvote it now, but the system tells me that, since 20 hours have passed, my vote is locked.

Is there any way to reverse this error of mine?

Comment: Some related discussions on meta.math.SE: [How to remove downvote after the grace period expired?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/22839) and [Is it alright to do an unnecessary edit so you can change your vote?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19574) (Of course, MO and math.SE are two separate communities and the views on many issues can be rather different.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I asked the guy who answered the question to edit his answer. The answer was edited and I upvoted it. Problem solved.